# How to access property for NumberAnimation and animate latter QML from first QML?

Tags: animation, qml, qstring

I have two qmls among which one contain animation say animation.qml and one contain data say data.qml.

I want to run my animation.qml for animating the content inside data.qml for that purpose I want to access the QString of QProperty in another model.

How to achieve the same?

I tried creating alias for the already defined property but it is not working using syntax

```
property alias differentNameForProperty: currentNameOftheProperty
```

Thank you in advance.

Here is an example,

Marks.qml

```
Item {
    Student {
        id: student
    }

    Item {
        SequentialAnimation {
            id: animination1

            NumberAnimation {
                duration: 1250
                target: student
                property: student.newMarks
                from: 0
                to: 100
            }
        }
    }

    Connections {
        target: marksModel

        function onCallMarks() {
            animination1.start()
        }
    }
}
```

Student.qml

```
Item {
    id: id_parent
    property double oldMarks: 10
    property alias newMarks: oldMarks

    // Using oldMarks to toggle
    // the visibility of elements
}
```

When the animation run from Marks.qml for `newMarks`. The changes will take place in Student.qml for `oldMarks` and animation will be played.
I hope my explanation is clear.
Thanks

Comment: the syntax would be as follows:  property alias differentNameForProperty : currentNameOftheProperty

Comment: Hi @JürgenLutz Thank you for the answer. 
I got "Invalid alias reference. Unable to find id "currentNameOftheProperty ".
I think it is searching it as an Item id still .

Comment: Could you please share a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Updated with an example. Please check @JürgenLutz

Comment: This is not a minimal reproducible example. `marksModel` is missing. At least make it so we can understand what you're aiming for. How does this example relate to your initial question?

Comment: In your NumberAnimation, does it work if you set `property` to just `newMarks` instead of `student.newMarks`?

Comment: No @JarMan . But student.newMarks start catching the value from other qml but don't update when animation runs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want...your example isn't really working, so I stripped it down to a version that does, but it might not be what you intended.

Your example has an issue with the `property` property in the `NumberAnimation`. This [property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-propertyanimation.html#property-prop) is of type `string`. So what you actually want to write is `property: "newMarks"` no need for the id prefix as this is already accomplished by the `target` property.

```
import QtQuick

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    component Student: Rectangle {
        id: internal
        property double oldMarks: 10
        property alias newMarks: internal.oldMarks

        width: 100
        height: 100
        color: "red"
        // Using oldMarks to toggle the visibility of elements
        opacity: internal.oldMarks
    }

    Student {
        id: student
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }

    SequentialAnimation {
        id: animation

        NumberAnimation {
            duration: 2500
            target: student
            property: "newMarks"
            from: 0
            to: 1
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: animation.start()
}
```

Comment: ok bro , thanks. I already tried not working.

Comment: What is not working? Please update your example so it shows your actual problem and is runnable without us modifying it.

Comment: The example I've shared is working. If it is not working for you, please tell me what the application outputs. If it doesn't fit your use case, please fix your example.